# Arduino function to fade from one RGB color to the next

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, led

For my Arduino project I have a [Neopixel RGB Strip](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide.pdf) with 72 LED's.

I can successfully change the colour of any of the LED's (at the moment I'm only setting the first one 0 for testing purposes) so I know my wiring isn't the problem here, it's my coding.

What I would like to do is be able to select a color and then another color and have the first color fade to the next color and so forth (much like the LIFX bulbs behave when using the iPhone application).

This is what I have at the moment:

I am logging output of all the variables to give you an indication of what's going on. I'm not 100% sure on where I'm going wrong or whether there's a much easier way to do what I'm after (I'm open to suggestions).

The function takes a parameter called `command`, which is a string separated by commas:

e.g. `255, 0, 0` (RED) or `0, 255, 0` (GREEN).

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Name  : tinkerSetColour
 * Description    : Sets the strip with the appropriate colour
 * Input          : Pin and value
 * Output         : None.
 * Return         : 1 on success and a negative number on failure
 *******************************************************************************/
int Rstart = 0, Gstart = 0, Bstart = 0;
int Rnew = 0, Gnew = 0, Bnew = 0;

int tinkerSetColour(String command)
{
    sprintf(rgbString, "Rstart %i, Gstart %i, Bstart %i", Rstart, Gstart, Bstart);
    Spark.publish("rgb", rgbString);

    sprintf(rgbString, "Rnew %i, Gnew %i, Bnew %i", Rnew, Gnew, Bnew);
    Spark.publish("rgb", rgbString);

    // Clear strip.
    strip.show();

    int commaIndex = command.indexOf(',');
    int secondCommaIndex = command.indexOf(',', commaIndex+1);
    int lastCommaIndex = command.lastIndexOf(',');

    int red = command.substring(0, commaIndex).toInt();
    int grn = command.substring(commaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex).toInt();
    int blu = command.substring(lastCommaIndex+1).toInt();

    int Rend = red, Gend = grn, Bend = blu;

    sprintf(rgbString, "Rend %i, Gend %i, Bend %i", Rend, Gend, Bend);
    Spark.publish("rgb", rgbString);

    // Larger values of 'n' will give a smoother/slower transition.
    int n = 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Rnew = Rstart + (Rend - Rstart) * i / n;
        Gnew = Gstart + (Gend - Gstart) * i / n;
        Bnew = Bstart + (Bend - Bstart) * i / n;

        // Set pixel color here.
        strip.setPixelColor(0, strip.Color(Rnew, Gnew, Bnew));
    }

    sprintf(rgbString, "Rnew %i, Gnew %i, Bnew %i", Rnew, Gnew, Bnew);
    Spark.publish("rgb", rgbString);

    Rstart = red, Gstart = grn, Bstart = blu;

    sprintf(rgbString, "Rstart %i, Gstart %i, Bstart %i", Rstart, Gstart, Bstart);
    Spark.publish("rgb", rgbString);

    return 1;
}
```

The problem is the colors are not fading between themselves.

Apologies if any of this is confusing. I can provide more information if necessary.

Here's the **output** selecting **RED** to begin with:

```
Rstart 0, Gstart 0, Bstart 0
Rnew 0, Gnew 0, Bnew 0
Rend 255, Gend 0, Bend 0
Rnew 253, Gnew 0, Bnew 0
```

Here's the **output** selecting **GREEN** directly afterwards:

```
Rstart 255, Gstart 0, Bstart 0
Rnew 253, Gnew 0, Bnew 0
Rend 0, Gend 255, Bend 0
Rnew 2, Gnew 253, Bnew 0
```

And then the **output** selecting **BLUE** after that:

```
Rstart 0, Gstart 255, Bstart 0
Rnew 2, Gnew 253, Bnew 0
Rend 0, Gend 23, Bend 255
Rnew 0, Gnew 25, Bnew 253
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no delay in there. It will fade very quickly, add a delay e.g. 5ms with `n` = 200 for a 1 second fade:

```
int n = 200;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Rnew = Rstart + (Rend - Rstart) * i / n;
    Gnew = Gstart + (Gend - Gstart) * i / n;
    Bnew = Bstart + (Bend - Bstart) * i / n;

    // Set pixel color here.
    strip.setPixelColor(0, strip.Color(Rnew, Gnew, Bnew));

    delay(5);
}
```

The other thing is your last value of `n` in the loop is 199, not 200, and thus `Rnew` etc don't have the correct final value. Change the comparison to be `<=` not `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```